# How do you install and earlier version of Android Tools and Platform Tools?

Tags: android, titanium, android-2.2-froyo

I am trying to get the android simulator working in Appcelerator's Titanium Studio on Windows 7, but it is not compatible with the latest Tools version (23) due to android issue #66740.  However I can't seem to find a way to install Tools version 22.

I used the Google installer from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

After installing if I run `titanium setup check` in the cmd window it says that the tools is unsupported version 23.0.2 and platform tools is unsupported version 20.

According to the Titanium Docs I need Tools version 22 and Platform Tools version 19.  I can't figure out a way to get earlier version of either, I can only install earlier versions of the Build-tools and SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use direct link, like http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r21.1-windows.zip - here is tools revision 21.1 with platform tools revision 19 (if you will download revision 22, just change the number; it will have r20 platform tools). 
You could find more in official documentation of Titanium: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_SDK)

Or, you could just use tool right in Titanium: Go in dashboard, in "get started" click on "Android SDK->Install or Update Android SDK", as seen in picture [1]. Then unhide settings, select empty folder to installing sdk, and versions of Android [2]. It will install, and it should work.

Sorry, couldn't post images so far, so here:
  (1): i.stack.imgur.com/bHHx5.png
  (2): i.stack.imgur.com/mXQwH.png

Comment: Thanks, I finally got titanium working installing an earlier version of the build tools with the way you mentioned.  I still can't figure out if you can install earlier versions of the tools and platform tools, but it works.

Comment: You can get the *Platform Tools* for MacOS here: `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_rXX.X.X-darwin.zip`, changing the X's to the version number you want.

Answer (score 0):

Go to android sdk manager and download all the versions you want to do

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I was using that SDK manager, but as shown on the screenshot on that page it only has the latest version of the tools and platform tools.  Also if you go to the Revisions page from the link on that page (<http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html>) it shows all the revisions, but only their notes and not how to download them.  Unless of course I am missing something obvious which is a distinct probability.

Comment: Which platform you are using mac or windows?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Eventually I have found the bug report that referred to it: [TIMOB-17221](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-17221). The bug is marked as fixed in SDK 3.3.0, but that version of SDK has not been released yet, so I was stuck again.

Then from [Appcelerator's Wiki](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Installing+Titanium+SDK+Continuous+Builds) I found out that there is a [Titanium CI builds page](http://builds.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#3.3.0). Download 3.3.0 from there, install and everything should start working again. At least it did for me. Good luck!